# How to add .p12 key to Java Spring from .pem file?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, pem, p12

I have this 3 files:

- certificate.crt
- certificate.pem
- certificate.key

The certificate.crt contains:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGmzCCBYOgAwIBAg etc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The certificate.key contains:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCA bla bla
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And the certificate.pem is more complex, it has:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgk etc etc
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGmzCCBYOgAwIBAg etc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGBjCCA+6gAwIBAgIR...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFdzCCBF+gAwIBAgIQ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So, certificate.pem contains 1 private key (diferent to certificate.key) and 3 certificates (the first is same to certificate.crt)

With this files, how can I get a .p12 file to insert into my Java Spring application?

I already tried with openssl convert the .pem file to a .p12 file but when I go to https//mydomain.com there is a not secure ssl message.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As you shortened the keys/certificate (that's OK for real keys) I cannot test but I would try to use this command with openssl: "openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -out clientcertchain.p12" => that should generate a p12-file "clientcertchain.p12".

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but in case, some one will need that in the future.

`sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey certificate.key -out keystore.p12`

Keep attention, that in most cases cert files are protected and reading operations are allowed only for root / sudo users. To verify that do ->
`ls -al`.

`-rw----r--  1 root   root   5717 Jun 13 21:49 certificate.crt`
Perform operations using root / sudo privileges or change permissions using chmod/chown.